# Infinite scroll using IntersectionObserver in React

Tags: reactjs, intersection-observer

I made infinite scroll using IntersectionObserver.

Here is the link.
https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-fog-qy1f7j?file=/src/App.tsx

I want to add `arr.length !== 0` to line 43 like this.

```
if (now.current !== 0 && arr.length !== 0 && now.current < testData.length) {
```

But `arr` is always empty inside of IntersectionObserver callback.

You can check it through the console.

I want to know why `arr` is always empty.